# Maximum Number of Subscribers in single channel of pubnub

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

For the group chat and single chat we are using pubnub.

what is the maximum number channels a single client can subscribe

I searched for this and got this below.

https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006151

> A single client may only subscribe to 50 channels at one time (with standard Mutliplexing). Using Channel Groups, a single client can subscribe to 10 channels and each channel group may contain up to 2000 channels.

In that is client can  subscribe only 50 channels or among all those only 50 channels are in active state?

we are not using channel groups.

we are using group chat in this manner

for group chat : group_21, group_25
for user chat : user_5, user_9

Comment: It is per client. You can have unlimited channels active across your pub/sub keys. And 50 is a soft limit for multiplexing and 2000 per channel group up to 10 channel groups (20,000 channels) is per client.

Comment: Can you please clarify, In that is client can subscribe only 50 channels or among all those only 50 channels are in active state?

Comment: What do you mean by active? As opposed to what?

Comment: Presence related perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

## Maximum Number of *Subscribers* in signal Channel of PubNub

> Answer: **Unlimited** -
>   *You may have unlimited number of subscribers in a PubNub Channel.*

#### Online / Offline Notifications Group Chat

However with [PubNub Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/) your activity tracking of users in a group chat channel will have soft limits.  You will want to make sure you plan your chat app and limit number of users based on activity notification settings.  You can [configure PubNub Presence settings](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043555-how-do-i-configure-the-channel-presence-feature-) to set limits on user notification settings.

You want to be mindful of user occupancy counts in your group chat.  This is because each user connecting to PubNub chat channels will generate a system notification of "online/offline" status for each user.